# How to make a filter that lists the name of each column with its data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a filter that associates each cell with the name of the column in which it is located.

Here is the desired result : [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opA0r.png)

I tried several basic formulas to invert the data (with transpose or query), but it's not suitable for this scenario, so I find myself stuck. Would you know how to do it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(A1:C1)&"|"&TRANSPOSE(A2:C)),"|"),"WHERE Col2<>''"))
```

[image]